# return single char literal as pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang

While the following function works with g++ 4.8.3 (with C++11)

```
char* fn() {
    return '\0';
}
```

clang++ 3.6 (with C++11) produces the following error:

```
cannot initialize return object of type 'char *' with an rvalue of type 'char'
```

So why is this difference and how is the best way to make this work with both compilers?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by "make this work"? What do you want it to do?

Comment: You do not want a pointer or a reference to a temporary value, especially since you know for sure that it's gonna be out-of-scope as soon as you return.
You can always return "", which should behave the same as what you're trying to do

Comment: If by "work", you mean "compiles", then it might "work" with g++. But it won't do what you want. A `char` is not a `char*`.

Comment: It's from a third party lib and I think the original author wanted to return a pointer to '\0' (original char).

Comment: Try `return "";` instead.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand why clang doesn't compile, but what happens on the gcc side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not convert char to char * but rather promotes the char '\0' to nullptr. It makes the same conversion it would make with a plain `return 0`

Comment: You're right, I just looked a bit more in the code and actually it should return a nullptr not a pointer to a character.

Answer (score 2):

> While the following function works with g++ 4.8.3 [...]

The fact that the function compiles does not mean that it actually works. The code returns a character constant that gets converted to a pointer.

If you want to return a pointer to `'\0'`, you need to allocate it in some place in memory that does not become invalid when your function returns, e.g. by using `static` or `new`:

```
char* fn1() {
    static char res = '\0';
    return &res;
}
```

or

```
char* fn2() {
    char *res = new char;
    *res = '\0';
    return res;
}
```

Callers of `fn1` need to be careful with changes that they make to `char` pointed to by the result, because it is shared among all callers.

Callers of `fn2`, on the other hand, must call `delete` when they are done with the result, in order to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Wouldn't returning "" behave the exact same? It should create an empty null-terminated string in static memory and return a pointer to the null-terminator.

Comment: @KABoissonneault String literals in C++ are `const char*`, so returning `""` would cast away const-ness.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: ... although it's worth noting the compiler won't complain: there's a deprecated loophole that string literals can be assigned to `char*`: however, it would still be undefined behavior to try and modify the string.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but @marom answer fits better, because I misinterpreted the intention of the code.